# i Can't pass three arrays to laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to pass three arrays to a view in laravel
but I got this problem

> Undefined variable: demmande (View: C:\wamp\www\project\resources\views\demmande\demmandes.blade.php)

i change the order of the arrays i can't pass the third array
here is my function in the controller

```
public function ViewDemmandes(){
  $listdemmande=Demmande::all();
  $listvillee=Ville::all();
  $listcategorie=Categorie::all();

  $villes = array('villes' =>   $listvillee, );
  $demmande = array('demmande' => $listdemmande, );
  $categorie = array('categorie' => $listcategorie, );

  return view("demmande.demmandes",$villes,$categorie,$demmande);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `compact()` method.

Try this line to return your data.

```
return view("demmande.demmandes",compact('villes','categorie','demmande'));
```

Just replace your code with this,

```
public function ViewDemmandes(){
  $listdemmande=Demmande::all();
  $listvillee=Ville::all();
  $listcategorie=Categorie::all();

  $villes = $listvillee;
  $demmande = $listdemmande;
  $categorie = $listcategorie;

  return view("demmande.demmandes",compact('villes','categorie','demmande'));
}
```

And you can retrieve those variables by

```
@foreach ($demmande as $data)
    {{$data->property}} //your property to define
@endforeach
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Great. So you can accept my answer :) so other stack users will know that this question has already correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the [Laravel Views documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views) I think that the `view()` method expects you to specify the template parameters using one array. You can combine your three arrays into one:

```
public function ViewDemmandes(){
  $listdemmande=Demmande::all();
  $listvillee=Ville::all();
  $listcategorie=Categorie::all();

  $data = array(
    'villes' => $listvillee,
    'demmande' => $listdemmande,
    'categorie' => $listcategorie, 
  );

  return view("demmande.demmandes", $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views) you can either pass an array as second parameter, as opposed to the list of all the parameters.

```
return view("demmande.demmandes", [
    'villes' => $villes,
    'categorie' => $categorie,
    'demande' => $demande
]);
```

or chain the `with` method to add more parameters (see the [Github page](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/View/View.php)).

```
return view("demmande.demmandes")
    ->with('villes', $villes)
    ->with('categorie', $categorie)
    ->with('demande', $demande);
```

Answer (score 0):

The view function will only accept a single array, however, you can nest your arrays within it like this -- and still access them by key from within the view.

```
return view("demmande.demmandes",['villes'=>$villes, 'categorie'=>$categorie, 'demmande'=>$demmande]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ViewDemmandes(){
  $listdemmande=Demmande::all();
  $listvillee=Ville::all();
  $listcategorie=Categorie::all();

  $villes = array('villes' =>   $listvillee, );
  $demmande = array('demmande' => $listdemmande, );
  $categorie = array('categorie' => $listcategorie, );

  return view("demmande.demmandes",compact('villes','categorie','demmande');
```

Answer (score 0):

## A simple example

View the controller in `app/Http/Controllers/SampleController.php`

```
 /**
 * @return View
 */
public function index()
{
    $movieList = [
        'Shawshank redemption',
        'Forrest Gump',
        'The Matrix',
        'Pirates of the Carribean',
        'Back to the future',
    ];

    return view('welcome', compact('movieList'));
}
```

and for example, See latest movie views in `resources/views/welcome.blade.php`

```
@section('content')
    <h1>Latest Movies</h1>
    <ul>
    @foreach($movieList as $movie)
        <li class="list-group-item"><h5>{{ $movie }}</h5></li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```